# Run sudo command from objective-c

Tags: objective-c

How can I run sudo commands from objective-c? I am able to run simple commands that don't require sudo with the following method:

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c" ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cmd], nil];


NSLog(@"run command: %@",cmd);
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *output;
output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return output;
```

When I run a sudo command i get the error: Operation not permitted.

From what I found online I need the gain authorisation. I read the Authorisation documentation from Apple but I doesn't specify a stating point.

The example EvenBetterAuthorizationSample from Apple doesn't work.

The application is signed with an Apple ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050687/how-to-use-nstask-as-root

Comment: Yes you need to gain authorisation.  Is that your question?

Comment: Are you trying to run a command as root, or are you actually trying to use it via the `sudo` command?  If you want to go through `sudo` you need to have permission for the user owning the process in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: I want to execute the command: "sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches" to clean the DNS cache.

Comment: Yes I need to gain authorisation. But how do I use the authorisation to execute the command.

Comment: I reviewed all the example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050687/how-to-use-nstask-as-root, it is not a possible duplicate, non of the example work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should study the [Authorization Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995), but if you want to do this using `sudo` you can.

What `sudo` requires is a password to authorise the execution, it normally gets this from the *terminal* - that is **not** the same as standard input though in a command shell the standard input by default is also connected to the terminal. The `-S` option of `sudo` instructs it to read the password from the standard input.

Following your existing design you can:

1) Add `-S` to the `sudo` command

2) The prompt for the password and any error messages, such as invalid password, will be written by `sudo` to the standard error. Create a pipe and attached it to the tasks `standardError`, or attach your existing pipe to both `standardOutput` and `standardError`, to capture this output.

3) Create another pipe and attach it to the tasks `standardInput`. Write the password followed by a newline to that pipe. When the task runs `sudo` will read the password and execute your command. Of course if the command itself requires input that will also be read from the pipe - so you must write it to the pipe.

HTH

Comment: The guide starts with: "Important: The authorization services API is not supported within an app sandbox because it allows privilege escalation." My application is an sandbox.

Comment: If you're in the sandbox you are out of luck - trying to invoke `sudo` should fail as any other application yours invokes inherits your applications sandbox limitations. You either need to not sandbox your app or find a non-priviledged way to accomplish your goal.